# MvvmCross - View not loaded

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I upgraded an old project to Xamarin.iOS Unified and MvvmCross 4.1.

When I run the app, I get the following exception:

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: View not loaded for MyView

My classes look like:

```
MyView : MvxViewController<MyViewModel> {}

MvxViewController<T> : UIViewController, IMvxBindingContextOwner, IUIWrappable 
    where T : ViewModelBase

ViewModelBase : MvxViewModel {}
```

I suspect I'm missing an interface or something on MyView to enable MvvmCross to operate correctly but I'm not sure what interface this might be.

I suspect this because I already had to hard code in mappings between the View and it's ViewModel, to enable MvvmCross to find the ViewModel through reflection/auto-discovery associated with MyView. That is, before this error, I was getting an unable to find associated ViewModel error.

If I make MyView implement IMvxIosView, this error goes away, and I then get a null reference on the ViewModel later on in my code, so somewhere that is not getting instantiated where it needs to. My impression was this should all be handled automatically by MvvmCross, but I might be wrong.

I'm looking at samples such as https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Xamarin.iOS-UI-project

where TipView contains

```
public new TipViewModel ViewModel {
    get { return (TipViewModel) base.ViewModel; }
    set { base.ViewModel = value; }
}
```

MyView's base has no such ViewModel property. What am I missing to have access to this?

TipCalc's sample code is still referencing the Cirrious namespace, so it's possible things have changed.

Any suggestions are appreciated. I'm new to Xamarin and MvvmCross (although experienced in Windows/iOS development), and I'm having trouble finding up to date documentation.

Comment: From your question it is not entirely clear what you are asking. Do you have a more complete reproducible sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
    var vc = this.CreateViewControllerFor(MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest(viewModelType);) as MvxViewController;
    vc.OnViewCreate();
```

The `vc.OnViewCreate();` should ensure your `View` is loaded.

And the line:
`this.CreateViewControllerFor(MvxViewModelRequest.GetDefaultRequest(viewModelType);) as MvxViewController;`

Should make sure that the ViewController is created with the ViewModel already set. That way you don't have to set it manually.

That method is an extension method defined in the `MvxCanCreateIosViewExtensionMethods` class https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/4.0/MvvmCross/iOS/iOS/Views/MvxCanCreateIosViewExtensionMethods.cs

-- Edit --

Another thing I noticed in your sample code is this line:

```
MyView : MvxViewController<MyView> {}
```

The type parameter passed into `MvxViewController<T>` should be the associated `ViewModel` for `MyView`, not `MyView` itself. So for example, you might have something like:

```
MyViewModel : ViewModelBase {}
```

and then:

```
MyView : MvxViewController<MyViewModel> {}
```

**-- UPDATE --**

You should be inheriting from the existing MvxViewController provided with MvvmCross. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/iOS/iOS/Views/MvxViewController.cs

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can instance the view without issue, but the CreateViewController is throwing a null reference in MvvmCross, and I can't see where right now since the library is packaged. I'll have to download the source to see.

That said, I think I'm doing something very wrong. According to the samples I've seen, all of this should just work.

Comment: Ah okay. I noticed something else in the code you provided, see the update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, I did in fact have MvxViewController templated with the ViewModel. I must have copied it in here wrong. My bad. Corrected the original question.

Answer (score 2):

**When creating MVVMCross ViewModels and Views,there are some requirements**

```
 1.ViewModel and View needs to have same name until "View" 
eg: MyView , MyViewModel

 2.You need to load stroryboard name to the Viewcontroller.
 eg:namespace [MvxFromStoryboard("MyView")] 
   public partial class MyView:MvxViewController  where TViewModel :MyViewModel

 3. When loading View, you need to have default constructor. 

   public MyView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle){}

 4.You need to bind viewmodel to the view.Most of the time in ViewDidLoad 
method in ViewClass 

 var set = this.CreateBindingSet<MyView, MyViewModel >();   
 set.Apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing IMvxIosView solved this particular error.

It looks like MvvmCross can't find the view unless it implements this interface.

Now I'm on to other errors.

Comment: You shouldn't need to implement IMvxIosView on a ViewController. All your ViewController should inherit from the MvxViewController class provided by MvvmCross: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/iOS/iOS/Views/MvxViewController.cs

Comment: @pnavk, using the built-in MvxViewController class in MvvmCross.iOS.Views namespace worked wonders. I'm not sure why the original developers made this other class but it doesn't seem to be needed anymore. If you reply with an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I added that as an update to my answer. Glad you got things working :)