# MvvmCross no bindings created

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I just upgraded a project from an older version of MvvmCross to the latest version, and I'm having trouble with bindings.

I'm aware of the LinkerPleaseInclude hack, and it looks like (at least some of) the properties I'm using are listed there.

I'm concerned about my usage of the Views and ViewModels. Here's an example.

```
public partial class HomeView : MvxViewController<HomeViewModel>

...

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    this.CreateBinding(BudgetTrackerButton).To((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.BudgetTracker).Apply();
    this.CreateBinding(LoginButton).For("Title").To ((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.LogMessage).Apply();
    this.CreateBinding(LoginButton).To((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.Login).Apply();
    this.CreateBinding(ContactApprisenButton).To((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.Contact).Apply();
    this.CreateBinding(AboutApprisenButton).To((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.About).Apply();
    this.CreateBinding(AboutThisAppButton).To((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.AboutApp).Apply();
    this.CreateBinding(FAQsButton).To((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.FAQs).Apply();
    this.CreateBinding(PrivacyPolicyButton).To((HomeViewModel vm) => vm.PrivacyPolicy).Apply();
}

public abstract class MvxViewController<T> : UIViewController, IMvxBindingContextOwner, IUIWrappable, MvvmCross.iOS.Views.IMvxIosView where T : ViewModelBase

...

}

protected MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel _viewModel = null;
public MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel ViewModel {
    get {
        if (_viewModel == null) {
            _viewModel = MvvmCross.Platform.Mvx.Resolve<T> ();
        }

        return _viewModel;
    }
    set {
        _viewModel = value;
    }
}

public MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest Request {
    get;
    set;
}

public object DataContext {
    get {
        return _viewModel;
    }
    set {
        _viewModel = (MvvmCross.Core.ViewModels.IMvxViewModel)value;
    }
}

protected MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.IMvxBindingContext _bindingContext;
public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext {
    get {
        if (_bindingContext == null) {
            _bindingContext = new MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext.MvxBindingContext ();
        }
        return _bindingContext;
    }
    set {
        _bindingContext = value;
    }
}
```

CreateBinding is from the MvxBindingContextOwnerExtensions.

When I hit CreateBinding, the view model has been made.

I understand DataContext to be the same as the ViewModel, and I only include it to conform to the `MvvmCross.iOS.Views.IMvxIosView` interface.

Am I missing a step somewhere? An interface?

Matching views to view models should happen automatically based on naming conventions, right? (They didn't.. in my case, I had to manually specify the mappings in my Setup class. Could be contributing to this problem.)

**Strangely enough, this works** (for the button title anyway, I haven't tested the other bindings, and I'm not interested in updating all the bindings across the entire application if the fix is simple):

```
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<HomeView, HomeViewModel>();
set.Bind(LoginButton).For("Title").To(vm => vm.LogMessage);
```

I can post more code if something else would be relevant. I'm also new to MvvmCross.

Comment: Is there still something unclear not working? (after your update)

Comment: Event handlers won't bind using this new method.

Comment: You mean, if you use sonmething like `set.Bind(LoginButton).To(vm => vm.SomeCommand);` ?

Comment: Yeah, here's an example:
    `set.Bind(LoginButton).To(vm => vm.Login);`

Login looks like:
    `public IMvxCommand Login {
    get { return _login ?? (_login = new MvxCommand(OnLogin, OnCanLogin)); }
    }`

No binding is made, the Login command property is not hit on button tap, and I don't see any diagnostic output (I have verbose logging enabled as far as I can tell)

Comment: have you called `set.Apply();` after you added all bindings?

Comment: If I call set.Apply(), then the Title binding that worked, no longer works, and the other command binding still doesn't work.

Is there something wrong with the original method that the original developers used that you can see? Or did the framework change such that the old method is no longer supported?

Comment: That's weird. To be honest, I've never seen / used the other method in 3+ years of using MvvMCross. But if it was working, I'd assume, that it should work even after the update. So the mentioned problem with the navigation comes into focus.

Comment: Is there a reason you have implemented your own MvxViewController instead of inheriting directly from the existing one in MvvmCross? https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3c735adc534a5df2d4730e9d58a08f7863c30cee/MvvmCross/iOS/iOS/Views/MvxViewController.cs

Comment: @pnavk: I'm not sure. It's old code that originated from another dev shop. I'm looking into removing the custom MvxViewController and seeing if the existing class works. I'll let you know what happens. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @pnavk Using the built-in MvxViewController in MvvmCross.iOS.Views fixed this issue as well as my other issue in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583805/mvvmcross-view-not-loaded . If you post an answer I'll accept it. Sven: It looks like the CreateBinding method works also, at least in a few places where I've left it in, although I had already converted to using the binding set most places, so this might have also fixed some issues, and is probably the recommended way. It looks like the navigation problem was the root of it all, as you suggested. Thanks!